# restoring from tray does not work (windowState)

Tags: c#, winforms, windowstate

I have followed some guides and it seems to be a very simple task. still, I cannot make it work.

I can minimize app to tray:

```
 private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
            {
                ntfIcon.Visible = true;
                ntfIcon.Icon = SystemIcons.Application;
                ntfIcon.BalloonTipText = "Antispin";

                ntfIcon.ShowBalloonTip(500);
                this.Hide();
            }
            else if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
            {
                ntfIcon.Visible = false;
                this.Show();
            }
        }
```

But I cannot make it restore from tray

```
   private void ntfIcon_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

        }
```

Simply, the window will not show up, even adding `this.Show()` after the windowstate

Any help please?
Compiling winform under win10

Comment: Put `this.Show();` in your DoubleClick event, before the WindowState line.

Comment: @OwenPauling Thank you for this. After a little tweak, it is working for me. After restoring, it will not focus the window, but it does not matter, so this is solution for me. Thank you.